# Stateless REST API with Social Login

Tags: java, rest, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

My app basically enforces stateless REST API methodology, that is, our web app (client) connects to the Rest backend and backend does not store any state of any kind.

Now I want to implement a Social authentication while keeping the API stateless still, here's what is working right now:

[image]

In the picture, it shows that we are able to "authenticate" with Facebook (we use Scribe Java library). And we can get the username or userid of the OAuth user.

Now the problem arise, since the Client connects to the server asynchronously and without any state. There is no "login" value here for the client. The client is still not logged-in.

- What can we do with the userId such that we can push back to the
  client a authorization token for its use?
- Should the "Backend" at point (2) in the picture just do a redirect to the client URL and pass the token as query parameter that the client will be able to save in the browser (this will be a new install of the app, i.e another browser tab)?

Related to this: http://outbottle.com/cors-stateless-rest-service-with-facebook-authentication/ 
However this article is using Facebook Javascript SDK not server-side.

Comment: Your question has all the keywords so I'm not sure where you're having trouble. You generate your access token and a refresh token, pass that to client after a succesfull login and now the client sends these along when he makes an API call that requires authentication. This is pretty much what OAuth(2) is about.

Comment: I just updated my post with the definite question